# Looping with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to the async programming and currently stuck with this simple task. I have a `Mysql` table which has 20k records and need to process all the records. The current approach is looping in batch of records.

```
let limit = 100;
let offset = 0;

sequelize.query(`Select * from abc limit ${limit} offset ${offset}`, {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then((records) => {
  // process

  return processResult; 
});
```

Therefore, i need to increase the offset in the `while` loop.

```
while (/*....*/) {
  let p = sequelize.query(`Select * from abc limit ${limit} offset ${offset}`, {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then((records) => {
    // process records

    return processResult; 
  });

  offset += limit; 
}
```

My question is what is the condition in the while loop in order to stop it ? Since `p` is always a `Promise`, thus I cannot use it as the stop condition

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.each()` of `bluebird` `Promise`.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

let limit = 100;
let offset = 0;
let queryStrings = [];
let max = 20000;

while (offset < max) {
    queryStrings.push(`Select * from abc limit ${limit} offset ${offset}`);
    offset += limit;
}

let p = Promise.each(queryStrings, (queryString)=> {
    return sequelize.query(queryString, {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then((records) => {
        // process records

        if(/* need to break */){
            return Promise.reject(new Error('...'));
        }
        return processResult;
    });
});
```

**update**

If you don't know the maximum, you can do some recursion:

```
let _iterate = function (limit, offset) {
    return sequelize.query(`Select * from abc limit ${limit} offset ${offset}`, {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then((records) => {
        // process records

        if (/* need to break */) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error(''));
        }

        offset += limit;

        return _iterate(limit, offset);
    });
};

let p = _iterate(100, 0);
```

Comment: Thank Adam, but i don't have the max value. 20k is just the estimation. It will increase more later. The loop should be like a cursor, moving batch by batch and if the batch is empty, then loop should stop. The thing is i don't know when it will be empty